# Abrir nova tela swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

Tenho um app webview, após a lauchScreen ele vai para a ViewController onde carrega a página, tenho uma classe que faz a verificação se existe conexão, e caso não exista gostaria de abrir uma nova tela avisando que está sem conexão ou mostrar um botão que de um reload no app, afim de tentar abrir novamente e caso exista conexão o app abrir normalmente.

Segue o código:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var WebView: WKWebView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       if(CheckInternet.Connection()){

           let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")
           let request = URLRequest(url:url!)
           WebView.load(request)

       }else{
          //caso n tenha conexão com a internet    
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um alertController, é um aviso simples onde você pode configurar as ações de cada botão, quando a ação que você deseja acontecer é só chamar esta função:

```
func createAllert(){
    //Criação do alerta
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Titulo do Alerta", message: "mensagem do alerta", preferredStyle: .alert)
```

//Criação dos botões de ação 
   let reload = UIAlertAction(title: "Recarregar", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
       //Ação ao pressionar recarregar
   }

   let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
       //Ação ao pressionar cancelar
   }    

   //Adicionando os botões no alerta
   alertController.addAction(reload)
   alertController.addAction(cancel)

   //Mostrando ele na tela
   self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}